# Object-oriented php - returning to previous object

Tags: php, oop, object

Did research, couldn't find answer.

Lets say I have those two classes:

```
class foo {

 function create_boo() {
  $boo = new boo($this); // creates boo
  return $boo; // returns boo object
 }

 function a() {
  //Do something complex here in class foo
  return $this;
 }

 function b() {
  //Do something complex here in class foo
  return $this;
 }

 function c() {
  //Do something complex here in class foo
  return $this;
 }

}

class boo {

 private $prev;

 function boo ($prev) { // Constructor
  $this->prev = $prev; //In my theory, this saves the previous object, so I can return to it, but doesnt work.
  //do something
 }

 function a() {
  //Do something complex in class boo
  return $this;
 }

 function b() {
  //Do something complex in class boo
  return $this;
 }

 function c() {
  //Do something complex in class boo
  return $this;
 }

 function return_to_foo() {
  return $this->prev; // should return back to previous object?
 }
}
```

Now, let me explain my problem and what I want to do. I can create easily class foo:

```
$foo = new foo();
```

And I can use functions over there

```
$foo->a()->c();
```

It uses now functions a and then c. I can put the order next to each other. Lets say I want to create boo and use functions over there too.

```
$foo->create_boo()->b()->c();
```

So, I created boo and use the stuff over there. But lets say now I want to jump back into previous tree without ending the command line and go back with one command, so it will start using foo commands instead?

```
$foo->create_boo()->b()->c()->return_to_foo(); //Next commands are from foo tree;
```

Is it even possible and if yes, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: While I realize you wrote this example in a hurry, it's unclear what you're trying to do and therefore hard to help.

Comment: `$boo` is going to be a local variable inside the method, created and destroyed every time you call the method. If you want that new $boo object to be stored in the container object somehow, you'll have to `$this->boo` it instead.

Comment: @Elven Can you change `new $boo` to `new boo` its bit confusing.

Comment: @Rahil Yes sorry. Was typo :).

Comment: Your code is fine. You have typo here `b()->(c)` I think you mean `b()->c()` instead.

Comment: Your code works for me :-)

Comment: Now I understand. Your problem is that your editor (eclipse) doesn't know what happened and doesn't provide the expected method hints.

Comment: @jgivoni Yeah. That made me also think that it doesn't work overall as well or I am missing something.

Comment: @Elven I think it's just the editor. The code actually works. If you know that {prev} is always of class Foo, you can phpdoc that in a comment above the method, which will probably help eclipse.

Comment: For the editor to work, you have to set the @return declarations for each method, specifying the type of the return value.

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP 5 constructors must be named `__construct()`. So in your example the method `boo` gets never be called and therefore the property `$prev` will not be set. Change your method `boo` to `__construct` and all should be fine.

**Edit:**

The documentation says that for backward compatibility, it will search for the old-style constructor function.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Comment: Weird, even if I do use __construct, even still it doesnt seem to work, almost as it doesnt find __construct() :/...

Comment: Okay, it seems that it does work and it is eclipses problem that It doesnt know how to go back into previous tree and suggest what to do next :/...